# When I Render my image, the result is a Black Screen

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I am trying to make a simple ink drop animation. The image looks great in Preview, but when I Render a second later the screen is just black. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here's the project file!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0iOn3LRcf5-YzBGRzlDQjgwQkE?usp=sharing

Would love some help!

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled nodes for rendering but there is no render layer connected to the composite node.

[image]

Add a in input>render_layer node and plug it to the composite node to get some output.

[image]